# ReactJS / Firebase: Set state from within authentication function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to set the state from within the function that gets returned when authentication is successful inside componentWillMount(). Accessing this.state inside handleAuthentication is undefined, however the displayName is correct (just within the wrong scope.)

```
componentWillMount() {

  ...

  // authentication
  function handleAuthentication(user){
    console.log(user.displayName);
  }
  var authHandler = function(error, result) {
    if(error){
      console.log(error)
    };
    handleAuthentication(result.user);
  }
  base.authWithOAuthPopup('facebook', authHandler);
}
```